# Getting a list of last day of month dates in PHP

Tags: php

These answers don't quite do what I want:

[Getting last month's date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php)
[How to find the last day of the month from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

I have the following code that is meant to print a select-box with all the last day of month dates from a given date:

```
            $last_case_date = $this->query_end_date();
            $increm_date = "2011-06-01";

            echo '<select name = "end_interval">';
            $increm_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$increm_date"));
            while($increm_date <= $last_case_date) {
                // next date is $increm_date + 1 month
                $increm_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$increm_date + 1 months"));
                // then we want the last day of this new date
                $month = substr($increm_date, 5, 2);
                $year = substr($increm_date, 0, 4);
                $increm_date = $this->last_day_of_month($month, $year);
                echo '<option value = "'.$increm_date.'" selected = "selected"'.'>'.$increm_date.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
```

where `last_day_of_month` is this:

```
   function last_day_of_month($month = '', $year = '') {
        if(empty($month)) {
            $month = date('m');
        }
        if(empty($year)) {
            $year = date('Y');
        }
        $result = strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
        $result = strtotime('-1 second', strtotime('+1 months', $result));
        return date('Y-m-d', $result);
    }
```

which I borrowed from [here](http://lutrov.com/php-last-day-of-the-month-calculation).

Strange thing that happens is that I get these dates:

`2011-07-31
2011-08-31
2011-10-31`

but no `2011-09-30` !  It probably has something to do with September only having 30 days or something right?

Can anyone spot the problem?  I've been staring at it for ages....  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the built in function for php

```
date('t', $timestamp);
```

So your function would look like:

```
function last_day_of_month($month = '', $year = '') {
    $month
        || $month = date('m');
    $year
        || $year = date('y');
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    return date('Y-m-t', $timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last day of the month, use:

```
date('Y-m-t', strtotime("$year-$month-01"))
```

`'t'` stands for the "number of days in the given month", i.e. for the last day. No need to add and subtract anything.

Answer (score 1):

The below will output a select box with options for the last day of each month in the current year:

```
echo "<select>";    
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){    
     echo "<option>".date('Y-m-t', strtotime(date("Y")."-".$i."-01"))."</option>";    
}    
echo "</select>";
```

If you want to set to a different year, simply replace `date("Y")` with, say, `"2010"`. You could, for example loop through a number of years, running the code to output the options for each.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem of your piece of code:

the original  $increm_date  is "2011-06-01";

a a certain point in the while cycle $increm_date is 2011-08-31 (last day of august)

the in the cycle you add a month so $increm_date is 2011-10-01 (first day of october, NOT THE LAST OF SEPTMEBER) so you call the last_day_of_month providing OCTOBER NOT SEPTEMBER.

I am not sure of this. To test try to print the  $increm_date before last_day_of_month is called