# php date next month gives wrong day

Tags: php, date

Why does

```
echo date("j/m/Y", strtotime("2015/01/31 00:00 next month"));
```

gives
3/03/2015
and not
28/02/2015

All I'm looking for is a todays date next month and if todays date is not valid then it'll give me the last day of next month.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting last month's date in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$thisMonth = "2015-01-31 00:00";
$thisMonthDate = strtotime($thisMonth);
$nextMonthDate = strtotime($thisMonth . ' next month');
if (date('j', $thisMonthDate) !== date('j', $nextMonthDate)) {
    $nextMonthDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $nextMonthDate) . ' last day of previous month');
}
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $nextMonthDate), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

What PHP is doing here is the following:

first it adds a month to your date, arriving to "2015/02/31"

then it realizes that this date does not exist, and that it is 3 days after "2015/02/28", which, translated in human terms, is "2015/03/03"

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180731/2718064) for a solution to your problem, as @kingkero suggested