# Get last month-name's date PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

### I need to get last day-name's date and last month-name's date in PHP.

For days, i did the following which is working fine :

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Monday"));    // Last Monday Date
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Tuesday"));   // Last Tuesday Date
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Wednesday")); // Last Wednesday Date
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Thursday"));  // Last Thursday Date
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Friday"));    // Last Friday Date
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Saturday"));  // Last Saturday Date 
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Sunday"));    // Last Sunday Date
```

How can i do for previous months which is not working :

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last January"));  // Last January Date
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last February")); // Last February Date
....
```

I can not use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last month'))` because it can be any month when i need my previous January or February dates. For example, i need last January's date in September.

### EDIT : My solution is

```
// Today : 2016-09-05
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("first day of January"));  // Output : 2016-01
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("first day of February")); // Output : 2016-02
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("first day of March"));    // Output : 2016-03
....
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("-1 year first day of January"));  // Output : 2015-01
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("-1 year first day of February")); // Output : 2015-02
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("-1 year first day of March"));    // Output : 2015-03
```

It is not exactly what i asked in my question, especially with months after the current one. Eg: `first day of December` while we are in September is NOT the last Septembre and is in the future but it do the trick for me because i have the correct year.

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can do something like

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of last month');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php#102947

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of previous month"));
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of previous month"));
```

[Getting last month's date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for find last day of previous month

```
date('Y-m', strtotime('first day of last month'));
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of -1 month"));
```

and this is for previous month

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-1 month"));
```

and last day of previous month

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of -1 month"));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of last month"));
```