# How can i parse a date to same day of previous month?

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

How can i parse a date to same day of previous month in PHP?

**Example:**

```
   input                 Output

2018-07-25     ->       2018-06-25
2018-07-31     ->       2018-06-30 (because there is no 31)
```

My code

```
$d = "2018-07-25";
$xd = date_parse_from_format("y-m-d", $d last month);
$output_d = date_create($xd)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Check to see if day is 29,30,or 31. If so, make sure the previous month has that day,. If not, go back to the last day of the previous month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTimeImmutable("2018-07-31");
$previous = $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
$lastMonth= $date->modify('last day of previous month');
if ($previous > $lastMonth) {
    $previous = $lastMonth;
}
echo $previous ->format('Y-m-d');
```

This code subtracts one month from the current date. If it is greater than the last day of the previous month we use the last day of the previous month instead.

[Demo](https://eval.in/1034918)

Comment: Thanks for this, it help me to create a loop for a entire year.

https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/39c3d

Answer (score -2):

Going back to one month is like subtracting one month from the existing date so with the help of strtotime and date we can solve this. like,

`$a = "2018-07-25";
$b = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($a."-1 month"));
$b is 2018-06-25`

Hope this helps.

Comment: is this return "2018-07-01" when input is "2018-07-31" ?

Comment: No for exactly 30 days you could use -30 days instead of -1 month

Comment: You can use the following command 
$b = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($a."-30 days"));

Comment: Neither example you provide works. -30 days on July 31 will be July 1

Comment: @JohnConde, Have you received the answer for this? if not check with the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php .