# PHP array containing 12 months and start with current month and decrement

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to get an array of 12 months starting with current month, decrement and be like "Mar 2022".

This is my code:

```php
$months = array();
$count = 0;
while ($count <= 11) {
    $months[] = date('M Y', strtotime("-".$count." month"));
    $count++;
}
```

But has some problems with months with fewer days.
For example: `dd($months[0]) => "Mar 2022"` and `dd($months[1]) => "Mar 2022"` had to be "Feb 2022".

Comment: I recommend you to use the `Carbon` library that is automatically included if you are using Laravel. This makes DateTime mutations so much easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution will as below:

```
<?php
$months = array();
$count = 0;
while ($count <= 11) {
    $prevMonth = ($count == 1) ? "first day of previous month" : "-$count month";
    $months[] = date('M Y', strtotime($prevMonth));
    $count++;
}
```

Refrence: [Getting last month's date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

use carbon.

```
    use Carbon\Carbon;
     

 
     for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
        array_push($months, Carbon::now()->subMonth($i)->format('M Y'));
    };
```